# Tanks in GTA V and Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Are the tanks in GTA V and Online susceptible to fire the same way they are in previous titles? Can RPGs be use effectively against tanks? Is there any way to neutralize the driver inside without destroying the tank?

Or are they just completely unstoppable, and if you encounter one in free mode you're basically dead?

Thanks~

EDIT: Also, can the treads be dismantled by damage?

Comment: Do many many Sticky boms do the job ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

So you can totally just rail the driver with a heavy sniper round by shooting through the vents in the back of the tank. It's really easy and hilarious. I'd have to say it is the most direct and reliable, and the least expensive approach.

Answer (score 9):

The only way to kill the driver without destroying the tank is to pull the driver out by one of the following:

- Trying to get in, which is pretty suicidal (assuming the driver hasn't locked the tank, of course)
- Calling Lamar to set a mugger on the driver to pull him/her out. This method requires you to be at least level 50.

Luckily, a tank is not completely unstoppable. It's not like in previous GTA games where it could take an infinite amount of car explosions when driving over them. It's also vulnerable to grenades, sticky bombs, the grenade launcher, RPGs, other tanks and the rockets of buzzards and fighter jets.
I haven't met anyone who shot it with an RPG (requires level 100) yet, but I can imagine that it's even more devastating than other explosive weapons.

Comment: Can an airstrike take a tank out?

Comment: Accepting this because I didn't think about calling Lamar at all that is a good idea. Yeah trying to climb in seems dumb because it's obviously going to be locked. Also, I am only level 60 but I do acquire RPGs from survival pretty often. Next time I see one I will try to get to high ground and call in an airstrike/use my own explosives and see how that turns out.

Comment: If that doesn't work I will call Lamar.

Comment: @ZeroStack It explodes, so in theory it should be able to do the job. In practice I never tried it, because air strikes are damn expensive compared to a mugger.

Answer (score 5):

I usually steal a cargobob helicopter which is always at merryweather in the city and occasionally at Trevor's airfield (online) and fly over the military base and have found multiple tanks not moving. If you can drop the hook and pick up the tank it's pretty easy from there. For whatever reason when you drop the tank someone gets out even though it was unoccupied (haven't figured that one out yet) but just kill him and you have yourself a tank. Keep in mind you have 5 stars after leaving the base so I usually take the tank and drop it by a train tunnel that way you can drive in the tunnel and no cops can get to you (watch out for trains!). I've found this method to be fairly simple.

Comment: What an amazing idea this is my new favorite answer. A fighter jet could be stolen with the same method, no?

Comment: cool method, but totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Doug this is not the answer to the question(s) you asked..

Answer (score 1):

I'm at level 101 and it takes about 10 RPG shots to take out a tank.

My advice, grab 4 or 5 other buddies, (who each have a RPG) to shoot at the tank at the same time, because if you go in solo (like myself) you can probably shoot off 2 or 3 rockets maximum, before the player sees you and kills you with 1 shot.

Answer (score 1):

I've shot down the driver of a Rhino Tank in GTAV Online, with a heavy sniper rifle. [Tank can be either still or moving , but it works. It comes down to how accurate you can lock on and get that instant kill] Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found its easiest to take out a tank by stealing a pedestrians car (killing them so you don't get a bounty) throw a stickie bomb on the hood, ram into the back of the tank and blow yourself up.

Answer (score 0):

Five stickybombs under a helicopter should work fine to stop a tank - just make sure to descend straight down onto the tank.

Answer (score 0):

Could sticky bomb a jet, dive straight down at the tank at max speed and eject at low altitude - not sure if ground/tank impact sets off the stickies, or if you time it right you can set them off.